# Can not remove rEFInd on my macbook pro

Tags: mac, multi-boot, uninstall

I am trying to remove rEFInd so I run the command

```
    sudo rm -r /EFI/refind
```

and I get the response: rm: /EFI/refind: No such file or directory

My location is /Volumes/ESP/EFI

anyone know what is the issue?

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs:](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/installing.html#uninstalling)

You need to mount rEFInd first using (assuming rEFInd is the first partition of disk0)

```
sudo mount -t msdos /dev/disk0s1 /Volumes/esp
```

Then

```
sudo rm -r /Volumes/esp/EFI
```